# How to refresh svelte 3 (not SvelteKit) component after component issues database update

Tags: svelte

I have an application in progress which lists the records in a database and provides a way to add, delete, move and update the records. So far, everything works fine for manipulating the data. The problem I have is finding a way to refresh the page after the database has been updated. The following is a slightly stripped down version of the component:

```
<script>
  import axios from "axios";

  let theAlbum = 1;
  let dbId = 0;

  const headers = { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json",},
  };
  const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3010/portfolios/";
  const dummyItem = { thumbnail: {title: "TITLE",image: "LINK",},
  };

  async function getPortfolio(portId) {
    const url = `${baseUrl}?portfolioInfo.portfolioId=${portId}`;
    const response = await axios.get(url, headers);
    const obj = response.data[0];
    dbId = obj.id;
    return obj;
  }

  async function patchPortfolio(port, portData) {
    const url = `${baseUrl}${dbId}`;
    const response = await axios.patch(url, portData.tempPort, headers);
  }

  async function insertRow(port, row) {
    let tempPort = await getPortfolio(port);
    tempPort.portfolioPics.splice(row, 1, dummyItem);
    const response = await patchPortfolio(+port, { tempPort });
  }

  async function deleteRow(port, row) {
    // code to delete row
  }

  let promise = getPortfolio(theAlbum);

</script>

{#await promise}
  ...waiting
{:then { portfolioInfo, portfolioPics }}
  <h2>
    &ldquo;{portfolioInfo.portfolioTitle}&rdquo;
  </h2>
  <ul>
    {#each portfolioPics as pic, picIndex}
      <li>
        <article>
          ...display data...
        </article>
        <article>
            <button
              on:click|preventDefault={() => insertRow(theAlbum, picIndex + 1)}>Insert
            </button>
            <button
              on:click|preventDefault={() => deleteRow(theAlbum, picIndex)}>Delete
            </button>
        </article>
      </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
{/await}
```

This is a work in progress, but not refreshing the display is a gamer stopper. There probably is a trivial answer to this, but I have been unsuccessful in finding it.

I've tried adding reactive variables but haven't succeeded in getting a response.

Comment: Please do not just paste all your code, reduce it to a minimal example first.

Answer (score 0):

There are two patterns that come to mind that would help here:

- Turn the `(#async promise}` into an `{#if data}`
- Turning the content of the `{:then}` into a separate component.

The problem is that the data is currently in a child scope and cannot easily be updated. So the above options can help making it easier to update the data.

E.g. the first method:

```html
<script>
    let data = null;
    async function loadData() {
      data = await axios.get(...);
    }
    
    loadData();
</script>

{#if data == null}
  loading...
{:else}
  ...
{/if}
```

This allows you to update `data` later.

---

With a separate component:

```html
{#await promise}
  loading...
{:then data}
  <Records {data} />
{/await}
```

```html
<!-- Records -->
<script>
  export let data;
</script>
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help. The page loads correctly as originally coded. Clicking on the insert or delete buttons will add or delete the appropriate down in the database. The problem is that I need the component to refresh. Manually refreshing the page causes the component to refresh and display correctly.

I tried the first approach and things work exactly like the {#await}{:then} case.

Comment: You have to update the `data` after edits/deletions/insertions, usually just sending the new data with the response to those requests. Assignments to `data` trigger reactivity and thus should update the UI. (If you are talking about reacting to changes made by *other users* that is a completely different story.)

Comment: I think the problem is not with the component updating, but {#each} loop. I tried the standard solution of adding portfolioPics = portfolioPics but that has not worked. Still investigating.

Comment: The each loop is lacking a key. [see docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each). To my knowledge you *cannot* change the variables created by `:then`, hence my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that is now working:

```
<script>
  import axios from "axios";

  let theAlbum = 1;
  let dbId = 0;
  let portfolios = []; // ADDED VARIABLE FOR MAIN ARRAY

  const headers = { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json",},
  };
  const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3010/portfolios/";
  const dummyItem = { thumbnail: {title: "TITLE",image: "LINK",},
  };

  async function getPortfolio(portId) {
    const url = `${baseUrl}?portfolioInfo.portfolioId=${portId}`;
    const response = await axios.get(url, headers);
    const obj = response.data[0];
    dbId = obj.id;
    return obj;
  }

  async function patchPortfolio(port, portData) {
    const url = `${baseUrl}${dbId}`;
    const response = await axios.patch(url, portData.tempPort, headers);
  }

  async function insertRow(port, row) {
    let tempPort = await getPortfolio(port);
    tempPort.portfolioPics.splice(row, 1, dummyItem);
    const response = await patchPortfolio(+port, { tempPort });
    portfolios = tempPort;  // REFRESHED MAIN ARRAY
  }

  async function deleteRow(port, row) {
    // code to delete row
  }

  let promise = getPortfolio(theAlbum).then(newPort => {
    portfolios = newPort;
  });  // ADDED THEN CLAUSE

</script>

{#await promise}
  ...waiting
<!-- {:then { portfolioInfo, portfolioPics }} ELIMINATED VARIABLE -->
{:then}
  <h2>
    &ldquo;{portfolios.portfolioInfo.portfolioTitle}&rdquo;
  </h2>
  <ul>
    {#each portfolios.portfolioPics as pic, picIndex}
      <li>
        <article>
          ...display data...
        </article>
        <article>
            <button
              on:click|preventDefault={() => insertRow(theAlbum, picIndex + 1)}>Insert
            </button>
            <button
              on:click|preventDefault={() => deleteRow(theAlbum, picIndex)}>Delete
            </button>
        </article>
      </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
{/await}
```

I'm assuming `portfolios` is now acting reactively and triggering the update now that `portfolios` is being updated each time the database is updated.